MVC routing with Areas
Using a blank MVC template I created two areas - General and Secure.
My understanding of routing is that if a specific link is not specified it will load the default page...
Public Module RouteConfig
Public Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes


    routes.MapRoute(
     name:="Secure",
     url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults:=New With {.controller = "Manage", .action = "Landing", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
     ).DataTokens = New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.area = "Secure"})

    routes.MapRoute(
       name:="Default",
       url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
   ).DataTokens = New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.area = "General"})





End Sub
End Module

So I would have thought that it would skip the first route and load /Home/Index, but it doesn't.
If I swap them around (default one first) it will load Home/Index, unless I run - Debug > Start Without running Debug - in VS with a page selected. In that case it tries to load /General/Controller/View and, of course, IIS throws the toys out as it isn't happy with that, it needs /Controller/View
With the default route loading first if I want to link to a page in the other area it needs to be in the format /Area/Controller/View, /Controller/View will not work.
I'm sure it's something very basic that I have missed.

did you try to set Default routes Config( hole line ) before Secure routes  ?  and after that defaults address ?

@MR Alam - Can you explain that in more detail? Hole line? Defaults address?

actually couldn't understand "swap them around" very well, my bad but i answered by some route example i created, i hop it will help you

the default page is the first address you want your client to see after call by your area.
For instance I have some routes like :
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Default",
       url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );

so,if my client call my address (https://localhost:44367/(whitout areas) )route it to HomeController Index
then i configuret my area Like :
context.MapRoute(
     "Group_default",
     "Group/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );

or
namespace GSS.Web.Areas.Group
{
    public class GroupAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "Group";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Group_default",
                "Group/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Group",action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}

so by above configuration , when my client call my area (https://localhost:44367/Group) it will routed to my GroupController inside my
Group areas.
if i use something like :
  routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Default",
       url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new {  action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );

my controller only reachable by: https://localhost:44367/Group/Group
because I have no default Controller value.
and also, in this scenario, you have to have some directories like this picture :


Thank you for your detailed explanation - I have marked that up whilst I figure out if it is the answer, although I did get a lot closer by messing around with both  AreaRegistration files.

@gchq Any time , and these two articles helped me to understand .
routing-in-mvc
asp-net-mvc-routing
